# Switches not changing state in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to write code which will oscillate the `set_player` between 2 states of `player1.name` and `player2.name`, I have written the following code with `val = 0` when it is initialised, inside a while loop. `set_player` never seems to change state and stays at `player2.name` the whole time. Any help would be great.

```
switch (val){
                case 0:
                    set_player = player1.name;
                    val = 2;
                case 1:
                    set_player = player1.name;
                    val = 2;
                case 2:
                    set_player = player2.name;
                    val = 1;
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing break statements. Without breaking after each case, `case 2` will always execute if val is either 0, 1 or 2. Therefore `set_player` ends up being assigned  `player2.name`.

```
        switch (val){
            case 0:
                set_player = player1.name;
                val = 2;
                break;
            case 1:
                set_player = player1.name;
                val = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                set_player = player2.name;
                val = 1;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: thanks! gah, I'm such an idiot. I thought the breaks in the examples I was reading was because they wanted to break the program after each switch statement...

Answer (score 0):

You should add `break;` line at the end of each case block:

`...
case n:
    ...
    ...
    break;
case n+1:
    ....`